# Load playlist with MPMediaQuery

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmediaquery

in my app I want to save user playlist in a plist file and load this playlist when app start.

this is the code that I use to save:

```
if (self.backgroundMusicItems) {
    NSMutableArray *songsID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    MPMediaItem *item;
    for (item in self.backgroundMusicItems.items) {
        NSNumber *songId = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
        [songsID addObject:songId];
    }
    NSString *documentdir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *filePath = [documentdir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"playlist.plist"];
    [songsID writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

and this is the code that I use to load:

```
NSString *documentdir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentdir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"playlist.plist"];

NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSMutableSet *predicates = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

if (myArray.count > 0) {
    NSNumber *songId;
    for (songId in myArray) {
        MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:songId forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
        [predicates addObject:predicate];
    }
    MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] initWithFilterPredicates:predicates];

    NSArray *mediaItems = [query items];
    if (mediaItems.count > 0) [GameOptions sharedClass].backgroundMusicItems = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:mediaItems];
}
```

myArray contains 2 items but [query items] method return 0 items. Where I'm wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for songs where MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID is set to the value for song1 *AND* song2 - which will always return zero results as it's logically impossible for any songs to match two different MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentIDs.

You need to run a query for each persistent id.